# JS parseInt string with commas

Tags: javascript

I have a string with 4 numbers with commas in between. I want to convert this string to an int, but I want to keep the commas.

```
function CreateCanvas() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); // grabs the canvas element
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // returns the 2d context object
                var imgageObj = new Image() //creates a variable for a new image


                var intCoor = 0;
                var Coor = "80,80,4,3";
                intCoor = parseInt(Coor);
                console.log(intCoor); // outputs 80

                imgageObj.onload = function() {
                    context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                    context.drawImage(imgageObj,intCoor); // draws the image at the specified x and y location
                };
                imgageObj.src = "img/9.png";   
            }
```

I want the output to be 80,80,4,3. Not 80 or 808043.

Edit: Sorry i forgot to sa that I need the numbers 80,80,4,3 as coordinates for a canvas.

Comment: How an integer can contain a comma ?

Comment: You need to split this array over coma and parse each element as a separate int. You can keep them in array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to make the first number after the first comma float after the `80` using `parseFloat` (that include floating numbers of `.`), until you replace the commas by ".".

```
var intCoor = parseFloat(Coor.split(",").join("."));
```

---

Some other option else is to keep each number in different arrays of sequence, easily generated by calling `split`:

`var intCoor = Coor.split(",");`

So you can get each separated number by declaring keys.

```
intCoor[0] // -- returns 80, the first number
intCoor[1] // -- returns 80, the second number
intCoor[2] // -- returns 4, the third number
intCoor[3] // -- returns 3, the forth number
```

Comment: @Sonny Glad that you got it solved. Your question was not clear. But I guess this would be the solution.

Comment: I'll try to be more specific next time. Thanks again for your time @PraveenKumar

Comment: See https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/1557/0/regex-vs-splitjoin for why Vinay's answer is better -- it's an order of magnitude faster!

Comment: @AidenWoodruff Here (Chromium/Opera) "Split And Join" was faster (tested 2 times). But I think it makes sense, since `RegExp` has code to be compiled.

Answer (score 16):

You cannot do that.. Use RegEx instead.

```
var price = "1,50,000";
var priceInNumber = parseInt(price.replace(/,/g, ''), 10);
```